# New function App Project is not creating on Installing Microsoft VS 2022

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-functions

I have downloaded Microsoft Visual studio on creating function App it is not creating new project, create button become disable after providing path for project. I have installed azure development tools as well. I have attached the image for reference create button is disable.

[image]

I have tried to update vs code but it is already updated

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, go to `Tools=>Get Tools and Features`, check if you have selected `Azure Development` in the *workloads* catalogue and all the required features.

- Uninstall `Azure Development` and reinstall again.

Make sure ***Azure WebJob tools*** is installed (check in Individual components).

[image]

- Navigate to `Tools=>Options=>Projects and Solutions=>Azure Functions`, click *check for updates*.

[image]

- Navigate to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools`, delete ***AzureFunctionsTools*** folder. It will be generated again when you open Visual Studio.
- Uninstall the ***Azure Functions Core Tools*** and reinstall again.

[image]

**References:**

[Develop Azure Functions using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs?tabs=isolated-process)

Comment: Thanks, the issue has resolved by deleting azure functions tools from AppData and update azure functions from Tools=>Options=>Projects and Solutions=>Azure Functions.

Comment: @AdilAsif, Welcome to Stack Overflow, the 1st Q&A Forum for all technologies. **Appreciate the efforts by accepting the answer that the user _PravallikaKV_ has provided the same answer in another way with the clear screenshots.**